# Document and best practices for configuration of a dedicated server (Centos) to serve just one website

Tags: mysql, django, apache-2.2, configuration, dedicated-server

I have just bought a dedicated server and they provide me a IP address, access info as root and machive with Centos 5.

I would like to serve my django app in that machine but because I have no experiences such server issues I don't know what is the best way to do that.

I have install mysql, python 2.7.1 and django as root and I think this is reasonable. But I have questions know.

1. Should I create a new user to deploy application and serve it on paache or doing that as root also ok ?
2. Should I create a user to manipulate with mysql ?
3. Django is running with Apache-modwsgi in my local. Should I configure Apache on server to run with mod-wsgi or is there any better method to it ?

I am a newbie on this server issues so please forgive me if my questions are so general to answer.

Any easy-to-read document (beginner-inter level) is also ok for me. I am also really appreciated if you explain your experiences or the best practices to do such configurations.

Comment: On CentOS Apache runs as the user "apache" and group "apache" by default (provided you installed it from the CentOS-Base repo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. don't run it as root, it is a safety risk
2. make a seperate user for mysql that only has the rights it needs, you can even make different ones : (if you only need to read for certain users only give that user read rights)
3. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide
4. install a firewall, close everything and open each port you need. I suggest you take a look at "vuurmuur" if you want something simple

for your user you do as root :

1. adduser someuser
2. mkdir /var/www/somedir
3. mkdir /home/someuser/dirwherethesourcecango
4. ln -s /var/www/somedir /home/someuser/dirwherethesourcecango (symbolic link)
5. chown -R someuser /var/www/somedir (set the rights so you can write)

Now when you log in as someuser, you can just add files to the dirwherethesourcecango, it is a symbolic link to /var/www/somedir.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer but I still have some confusion on users. For example, where should I put the  source code of my app ? Because I have just used VPS, there was a public_html folder,symlink to www folder and soon. In this case, should I define a user and make a symlink to /usr/local/www/ from /home/username/ ? Could you illustrate the tree I must have ?

Comment: I'll add it to my answer